# Using python, how can i draw objects on image and move, find it

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program which can draw some objects on an image

the features what i need are

1. can draw vector(or bitmap) objects (eg. dots, lines..) on pre-existing image file (especially jpg format)
2. can keep track that objects and find by id or x,y coordinates
3. can move/modify/remove that objects

please recommend some nice library or code samples for these features.

(I'm trying with WxPython.PseudoDC, but I think it is not what i'm looking for)

thanks.

Comment: I would use [Pygame](http://pygame.org/news.html) for this.

Answer (score 1):

[PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm) is the library for you. You can use [ImageDraw class](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagedraw.htm). There is no integration between PIL and wxPython, so you should convert from one Image class to another, but that's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

For interactive graphical programming, look at [pyprocessing](http://code.google.com/p/pyprocessing/).

Answer (score 0):

how about [guiqwt](http://packages.python.org/guiqwt/index.html),

Here is an example:

http://packages.python.org/guiqwt/examples.html#image-plot-tools

[image: guiqwt plot tools]